# The time complexity for a code segment

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

From an online notes, I read the following java code snippet for reversing a string, which is claimed to have quadratic time complexity. It seems to me that the “for” loop for i just iterates the whole length of s. How does it cause a quadratic time complexity?

```
public static String reverse(String s)
{
  String rev = new String();
  for (int i = (s.length()-1); i>=0; i--) {
      rev = rev.append(s.charAt(i));
  }
  return rev.toString();
}
```

Comment: you are also concatenating to string, which is quite costly as they are immutable. (your code has some errors, it won't compile)

Comment: This won’t return the string in reverse as it will always prepend an additional space to it.

Comment: And why somebody wrote this, instead of just using String's `reverse` method is beyond me (unless they wanted the extra space, which is just... bizarre).

Comment: Let n = the length of s and f be the time complexity function of the algorith.  If the algorithm just iterates the whole length of s, then there must exist some constants a and b such that f(n)<a*n^2 for all n>b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static String reverse(String s)
{
  String rev = " ";
  for (int i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
  rev.append(s.charAt(i); // <--------- This is O(n)
  Return rev.toString();
}
```

I copy pasted your code. I'm not sure where you get this but actually String doesn't have `append` method. Maybe `rev` is a [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or another [Appendable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html).

Answer (score 2):

Possibly because the `append` call does not execute in constant time.  If it's linear with the length of the string, that would explain it.

Answer (score 2):

`append` has to find the end of the string, which is Ο(n). So, you have an Ο(n) loop executed Ο(n) times.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think String has an append method. So, this code won't compile.

But, coming to the problem of quadratic complexity, let us assume that you are actually appending the string with a character using '+' operator or the String.concat() method. 
The String objects are immutable. So, whenever you append to a string, a new string of bigger length is created, old string contents are copied to it and then the final character is appended, and the previous string is destroyed. So, this process takes more and more time as the string grows.

The appending loop takes O(n) time but for every loop you take O(n) time to copy the string character by character. This leads to quadratic complexity.

It would be better to use StringBuilder or StringBuffer. However, I guess the time complexity you mentioned would be with older java compilers. But, new advanced compilers would actually optimize the '+' operation with StringBuilder.