# What is the cost of + operation on a String in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, runtime, addition

For this for loop, is the run time O(n) or O(n^2):

```
char[] ar = new char[1000];
String s = "";
Arrays.fill(ar, 'a');
for(Character c: ar){
    s += c;
}
```

So basically, what is the run time of + on a String? How does it work behind the scene in Java?

Comment: Related (a few are borderline duplicates): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916984/the-time-complexity-for-a-code-segment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635659/strings-are-immutable-that-means-i-should-never-use-and-only-stringbuffer http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/string-manipulation-complexity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java strings are immutable.  Every time you do:

s+=c;

You're really saying:

s = new String(s + c);

new String(s + c) must allocate a string of length  s + 1, or:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
...
etc.

Since Sum(1..N) == (n + 1) (n / 2), this is O(n^2).

One of the cases where StringBuilder is a definite advantage.

Answer (score 5):

From "Effective Java" by Josh Bloch; Item 33 in the book:

> Using the string concatenation operator repeatedly to concatenate n strings requires time quadratic > in n...When two strings are concatenated, the contents of both are copied.

Use StringBuilder. I believe its performance is O(n).

Comment: How about StringBuffer? Which one is better?

Comment: StrignBuilder is preferred over StringBuffer in new code when the synchronization is not required.